# How debuging twisted application in PyCharm

Tags: twisted, pycharm

I would like to debug a Twisted Application in PyCharm

```
from twisted.internet import defer
from twisted.application import service, internet
from txjason.netstring import JSONRPCServerFactory
from txjason import handler

class Example(handler.Handler):
    def __init__(self, who):
        self.who = who

    @handler.exportRPC("add")
    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def _add(self, x, y):
        yield
        defer.returnValue(x+y)

    @handler.exportRPC()
    def whoami(self):
        return self.who

factory = JSONRPCServerFactory()
factory.addHandler(Example('foo'), namespace='bar')

application = service.Application("Example JSON-RPC Server")
jsonrpcServer = internet.TCPServer(7080, factory)
jsonrpcServer.setServiceParent(application)
```

How to run app from command line I know, but how to start debugging in PyCharm can't understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new [Run Configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html) in PyCharm, under the "Python" section.

If you start this application using `twistd`, then configure the "Script" setting to point to that twistd, and the "script parameters" as you would have them on the command line. You'll probably want to include the `--nodaemon` option.

You should then be able to Run that under PyCharm, or [set breakpoints](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/using-breakpoints.html) and Debug it.