# how to debug twisted trial unittest in pycharm

Tags: unit-testing, debugging, pycharm, twisted, trial

I am new to twisted and I have a twisted unit test in python, and I want to  debug in pycharm with trial.

I can run the tests in command line fine (for e.g. like :~ nathan$ trial smoke_tests ) but would like to step through the test in an IDE

in another question 
[How debuging twisted application in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970894/how-debuging-twisted-application-in-pycharm)

It has been suggested that "configure the "Script" setting to point to that twistd" . so for 'trial' I tried pointing to /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/trial/runner.py , but that fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Script**
Assuming your working directory is */home/myself/mypythonproject/myworkingdirectory* ,

Create a python file in your working directory with name trial_try.py. This is a copy of  */usr/local/bin/trial*. So use a copy of the version you have.

```
    import os, sys

    try:
         import _preamble
    except ImportError:
        try:
            sys.exc_clear()
        except AttributeError:
            # exc_clear() (and the requirement for it) has been removed from Py3
        pass

    # begin chdir armor
    sys.path[:] = map(os.path.abspath, sys.path)
    # end chdir armor

    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()))

    from twisted.scripts.trial import run
    run()
```

**Configuration**
Create a new Run Configuration in Pycharm.

for Script Enter

*/home/myself/mypythonproject/myworkingdirectory/trial_try.py*

for Parameters Enter you Parameters that you would use when running trial on the command line

for e.g. test_smoke

for Working directory Enter

*/home/myself/mypythonproject/myworkingdirectory*

You should be all Set !