# run in twistd instead of python

Tags: python, pycharm, twisted, autobahn, twistd

I need to debug my twisted application.  I am using pycharm and from what I understand I can start my application in twistd with the --no-daemon option in order to step through the code.

I have the following code to start the server.

```
def main():
    log.startLogging(sys.stdout)

    contextFactory = ssl.DefaultOpenSSLContextFactory(os.environ['SSLKEY'],
                                                     os.environ['SSLCERT'])
    factory = WebSocketServerFactory(u"wss://0.0.0.0:8080")
    factory.protocol = MyServerProtocol
    resource = WebSocketResource(factory)

    root = create_root()

    saml_manager = SamlManager()
    saml_manager.init_app(root)

    root.putChild(b"ws", resource)

    site = Site(root)

    reactor.listenSSL(8080, site, contextFactory)
    reactor.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I see twistd has a -y option but I have not been able to get it to run my app.

My directory tree has is as follows.

```
.
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── auth.py
│   ├── certs
│   └── index.html
├── run.py
├── saml
│   └── settings.json
└── venv
    ├── bin
    ├── include
    ├── lib
    └── pip-selfcheck.json

7 directories, 6 files
```

I have been running the application by executing run.py which calls the main() function.

How can I start this application with twistd on the command line so I can debug the app?

For reference I am refering to [How debuging twisted application in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970894/how-debuging-twisted-application-in-pycharm?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) in order to try and debug the twisted app in pycharm.

If there is a better way to do this so I can set breakpoints in requests please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Disregard this question.  I apparently had a bad decorator that was causing a redirect loop and also prevented me from debugging.  Once I remove that decorator I am able to debug like normal.